# Elementary dvisibilty problem involving power sums.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Prove that $1^n + 2^n + \cdots + m^n$ does not divide $(1+2+ \cdots +m)^n$ for any even integer $n\geq 2$.

For $n\leq 4$, the result easily follows from the relevant identities. For $n\geq 6$, i suspect that Bernouli polynomials might be the best approach, but haven't found how ?

> Cross-posted at Math Overflow: ["On the divisibility of a certain power sum"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228698/on-the-divisibility-of-a-certain-power-sum)

Comment: I think this question might be best suited for MO, can i cross-post it ?

Comment: Well, even @MO it seems not to be having straightforward answers yet. In any case, kindly waiting for the solutions.